# Cant get data from nsdictionary of json with objectforkeys

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I'm getting a json in a NSDictionary. I am watching this json if I do a NSLog of the NSDictionary.

```
NSLog->>  {"login":{"pass":"yeeply123","user":"Yeeply"}}
```

I get places dictionary here:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSError *thisError;


    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myConnectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&thisError];
    NSLog(@"Prueba %@", parsedObject);
    [self.delegate requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:placesDictionary];
}
```

and I pass it to other function as placesDictionary
But when I try to get data from this NSDictionary with this sentence:

```
 NSDictionary *userDictionary= [placesDictionary objectForKey:@"login"];
 NSString *pass=  [userDictionary objectForKey:@"pass"];
```

I get an error like this:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7172f10
```

I don't know what is happening, I did it in other project and it worked..

Thank you

Comment: can you print your Nslog placesDictionary .

Comment: what is placesDictionary ? can you show the code .

Comment: your placesDictionary implicitely convertd into string that is the problem.

Comment: Your parsedObject is an array not a dictionary.

Comment: can you show this NSLog(@"Prueba %@", parsedObject);

Comment: This was NSLog(@"Prueba %@", parsedObject); = [{"pass":"example23"},{"user":"example"}] since now is {"pass":"yeeply123","user":"Yeeply"} But still doesnot work

Comment: That message is subtly telling you **IT'S NOT A DICTIONARY!!**

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You server does not sent valid JSON. What you get from the server is

```
"[{\"pass\":\"example23\"},{\"user\":\"example\"}]"
```

which is a JSON *string* (containing JSON data). So the top-level
object is not a dictionary or array, which is invalid according to the JSON specification.

Your call

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myConnectionData:...]
```

succeeds only because because of the the `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments` option, otherwise
it would fail.

The string itself contains valid JSON data, so what you can do is to apply another
JSON parsing operation to the contents of the string:

```
NSString *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myConnectionData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&thisError];
NSData *innerJson = [parsedObject dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *innerObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:innerJson options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&thisError];
```

The `innerObject` is now an array of two dictionaries, which you can access like:

```
NSString *pass = [[innerObject objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"pass"];
```

(Of course a better solution would be to fix the server to send proper JSON.)

Comment: I fixed the server. Now, I have this dictionary(This is a NSlog output)-> {"login":{"pass":"example123","user":"example"}} 

Im using this code to get the data:
 `NSDictionary *userDictionary= [placesDictionary objectForKey:@"login"];
    
NSString *pass=  [userDictionary objectForKey:@"pass"];`

and it still does not work

Comment: @roxeman3: That does not look like a dictionary! It still looks like a string. Did you try my code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try it because I want to solve as a Dictionary. Do you mean that this {"login":{"pass":"yeeply123","user":"Yeeply"}} is not a dictionary? I checked it in a json validator and everything is ok..

Comment: @roxeman3: That is a **string** containing valid JSON! The NSLog output of a dictionary would look like `{ pass = yeeply123; user = Yeeply }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is an array of dictionaries. Make sure that the `placesDictionary` is a dictionary, from the error it seems like it is a string. There is no error in your code.

EDIT:

From the log placesDictionary is an array.

```
NSDictionary *dict = placesDictionary[0];
NSString *itemToPassBack = dict[@"pass"];
```

Comment: I have an error when I write this sentence :
    NSDictionary *dict = placesDictionary[0];

Comment: @roxeman3 can you show how you are assigning value to placesDictionary?

Comment: I sent this parsedObject `[self.delegate requestJSONFinishedWithParsedObject:parsedObject];`  but in the other side is placesdictionary